# Webpack returns ENAMETOOLONG when running eslint-loader

Tags: webpack, eslint

I have eslint-loader setup as a preLoader in my webpack.config file. However it seems when processing a file that exceeds a certain size, webpack throws the error ENAMETOOLONG. If I don't have webpack run eslint-loader then everything works fine. Also, if I run eslint from the command line against the same file there are no problems.

The test file I am using to try to pinpoint the issue declares ~100 variables, nothing else. If I delete ~20 of these variables then everything runs fine.

I am in a Windows 10 environment btw. I have seen some issues related to file paths that are too long from nested node_module directories, but this would appear to be unrelated.

From my package.json file:
"eslint": "^2.11.0",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "^9.0.1",
"eslint-loader": "^1.3.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^1.8.1",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^1.2.2",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^5.1.1",
"webpack": "^1.13.1",

Any advice, or suggestions for other things to test, is much appreciated.

Comment: Is looking very much like when there are too many warnings or errors reported by eslint that this is causing webpack to thrown this error

Answer (score 0):

My javascript had so many warnings and errors reported that it was causing this issue. Once I got the warnings and errors down to a smaller amount the issue was resolved